# Grails where query associations

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a two domain classes:

```
class MyForm{
    ....
    static hasMany = [items:MyFormItem]
}

class MyFormItem{
    String type
    static belongsTo=[myForm:MyForm]
}
```

I want to query MyForm and find all where there is one type of item but not another.

So, I want to find all MyForm where there is a MyFormItem with a type of 'something' but it cannot also have a MyFormItem with a type of 'other', for instance.

I was trying a where clause, but that seemed to just grab everything:

```
MyForm.where{
    items{type=='something' && type!='other'}
}
```

Is there a way to do this with one query utilizing GORM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using the [withCriteria](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html) method.

```
def results = MyForm.withCriteria {
    items {
        eq('type', 'something')
    }
    items {
        ne('type', 'other')
    }
}
```